# Runtime Error while trying to pull the custom error page in IIS 7 in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am using the below code to display the 404 custom error page.

```
<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="../403.htm" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Unsecure/404.html" />
    </customErrors>
```

i am trying to use the below url's after i hosted

www.abc.com/login.aspx is my original url but when i use www.abc.com/kdfjdkfjd.aspx i am able to see the 404 page but when i am trying to use the url **www.abc.com/login.apsx.(fullstop is added at the end)** i am getting the below error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

I have hosted this in window 2008 server R2.

Comment: Does `Unsecure/404.html` exist?

Comment: Yes it is existed. @AlexKudryashev

Comment: what is the location of Unsecure folder?